# Swift closure type inference

Tags: swift

Why is it that this works:

```
var numbers = [20, 19, 7, 12]
numbers.map({
(number:Int)->Int in
if number % 2 == 0 {return number * 3}
else {return 0}
})
```

but not this:

```
var numbers = [20, 19, 7, 12]
numbers.map({
(number) in
if number % 2 == 0 {return number * 3}
else {return 0}
})
```

which gives the error message: "Cannot convert the expression's type 'Array<U>' to type 'U'"?

Apple's documentation says, "It is always possible to infer parameter types and return type when passing a closure to a function as an inline closure expression."

Comment: beta versions tend to have bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I can whittle your erroring example down to the simplest version:

```
let x = numbers.map({
    (number) in
    return number
    })
```

Note that you're not actually using an inline closure expression.  An inline version of what you're trying to accomplish would be:

```
numbers.map({$0 % 2 == 0 ? $0 * 3 : $0})
```

Comment: My understanding is that "inline closure" refers to a closure defined as its being passed rather than as a standalone closure (a named function).  Is that how you're using it, or do you mean a closure defined in a single line?  Either way, it seems as though Swift should be able to infer the necessary types...  Why wouldn't your "simplest version" work, for example?