# Type Error in closure (translated code from obj c to swift)

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6

I am trying to use a library which is written in objective c in my swift application.
I tried to translate a snippet from the readme to swift code - But I get a type error I don't understand.

Obj.C code from readme:

```
[self.client logonWithUsername:self.username.text password:self.password.text responseCallback:^(NSDictionary *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        [self handleFailedAuth:error];
        return;
    }
    [self handleSuccessfulAuth];
}];
```

My translation to swift:

```
    var username = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("username")
    var password = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("password")

    client.logonWithUsername(username, password: password, responseCallback: {
        (response: NSDictionary, error: NSError) in
            if(error){
                handleFailedAuth(error)
                return;
            }
            handleSuccessfulAuth()
        }
    )
```

I Get [NSObject: AnyObject]! is not a subtype of NSDictionary on the line where the parameters of the closure are defined. How is that possible? I am using the same types as in the example.

Comment: try adding an exclamtion point after NSDictionary. NSError as well

Comment: Yup, I'd say that's the problem. You're not using *quite* the same types, as an NSDictionary* in Objective C can be nil. An NSDictionary in Swift can't be nil: you need an Optional of some kind. These object pointers are bridged from Objective C headers as implicitly unwrapped, hence the need to use `NSDictionary!`.

Comment: just remove the type and let compiler figure it out for you

Comment: Yup, fair point: it's always possible to infer types in this situation. Though apparently [it might be a little buggy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050146/swift-closure-type-inference) in the beta.

Comment: Well, I don't know why but the compiler does not really help me finding the correct time - probably because of the beta... Using NSDictionary! did not really help - now the error is [NSObject: AnyObject] is not identical to NSDictionary

Comment: Using [NSObject:AnyObject]! as type resolved the problem...

Comment: Yikes... Don't store the user's password in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Whats the properway to store it? - just as a side note: i dont have a login or registration form this password is generated automatically by the app.

Answer (score 0):

Your Swift should probably read the following:

```
var username = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("username")
    var password = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("password")

    client.logonWithUsername(username, password: password, responseCallback: {
        (response: NSDictionary?, error: NSError?) in
            if(error){
                handleFailedAuth(error!)
                return;
            }
            handleSuccessfulAuth()
        }
    )
```

This is because Swift optionals in some ways replace the way you used to pass nil in objective-c.  So because the NSDictionary might be nil and the NSError might be nil, you put a ?-mark after them, then conditionally unwrap w/ a !-mark inside the block when you need to access the value of that

Answer (score 0):

You're explicitly specifying the block/closure parameter types in Swift, and the Swift compiler does not have enough information about the `NSDictionary`. This is because the Swift `Dictionary` is more strongly typed than the Objective-C `NSDictionary`.

The error message says (admittedly, pretty cryptically) that the exact type Swift is expecting is a `Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>!`.

There are a couple of ways to solve this. One is to be more explicit about your NSDictionary parameter in the Swift closure definition:-

```
  client.logonWithUsername(username, password: password, responseCallback: {
    (response: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>!, error: NSError) in
      // ... handler body
      }
  )
```

A somewhat easier way is to not try to tell Swift about the types at all and let the compiler infer what it needs:-

```
  client.logonWithUsername(username, password: password, responseCallback: {
    response, error in
      // ... handler body
      }
  )
```